# Error with searchbox on wordpress page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this site http://www.laeconomista.com/
And installed a searchbox 
but when I try to write on this and try to search something

the searchbox automatically reload the page, and does'nt work fine

I think that is a problem with css or something  with the header form input (submit or text)

Please can help me how can fix this

thanks for all...

Comment: Please include the code rather than linking off to somewhere (especially with a short link).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some relevant code (and maybe a JSFiddle example) here. With only an external link, the question will have no value to future readers once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
<h1 id="logo"><a href="http://www.laeconomista.com/">La economista          </h1>
```

You forgot to close your link (there is no `</a>`) which means that the entire form is inside the link. So as soon as you click on the form, you are linked back to the same page.

Change the line to:

```
<h1 id="logo"><a href="http://www.laeconomista.com/">La economista</a></h1>
```

And it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you have an anchor tag which has not closed, you should just remove it. You should remove it or close it.

```
<a href="http://www.laeconomista.com/"> REMOVE THIS
    <form id="searchform" action="http://www.laeconomista.com/" method="get" role="search">
        <div>
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Buscar por:</label>
            <input id="s" type="text" name="s" value="">
            <input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="Buscar">
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Updated**

Apparently it's because of a unclosed anchor in the ... see @daverandom's post!!

Comment: Actually he doesn't, he just forgot to close the anchor on the logo. If you view the raw source and compare it against the debug display, you will see the difference. But you're close...

Comment: That's problem with viewing source using firebug! I'll edit my answer. :)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts yeah, hence the "That's problem with viewing source using firebug!" ;)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts nah I just got bored and upvoted DaveRandom

Comment: haha - fair enough. I shall delete my comments.